# py project works but pyinstaller gives error related to pulp

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, pyinstaller, pulp

I'm working on a project for linear optimization with pulp. When I normally "run" the file it work good but I've some problems when I try to convert it into a .exe file with **pyinstaller**.
If I run the .exe file from a command prompt are reported that errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "price.py", line 116, in <module>
  File "site-packages\pulp\pulp.py", line 1713, in solve
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'actualSolve'
[9468] Failed to execute script price
```

The part of the code I'm having an issue with:

```
#type of problem
group_division = pulp.LpProblem("Group_division", pulp.LpMinimize)

#objective function to minimize
group_division += objectiveFunction(external_groups, internal_groups)

#specify the maximum number of groups
group_division += sum([x[group] for group in external_groups]) <= max_groups,                             
"Maximum_number_of_groups"

#every thickness must appear once 
for cutType in cutTypes:
group_division += oneCutConstraint(x, y, external_groups, internal_groups, cutType) == 
1,"Must_appear_%s"%cutType

#solve the problem    
group_division.solve()
```

Comment: Are you able to share a minimum amount of code to reproduce the problem? It seems like you have ended up with a NoneType object where you should have a solver object. I'm guessing because when running from your executeable pulp can't see the solver. What solver(s) do you use when running as python code?

Comment: @kabdulla I run the code with spyder and also with JupyterLab and I have no errors. I think that pyinstaller and pulp have some "communication" problem. What do you think about?

Comment: From what I can see pulp library has been found from the pyinstaller running environment but it looks like the solver (which is separate to pulp) cannot be found.

Comment: To check id recommend running (locally and then through pyinstaller-gnerated exe) the following `pulp.pulpTestAll()`. You will then know which solvers are available from where.

Comment: Hmmm... used to be you could just do `import pulp` followed by `pulp.pulpTestAll()` as per the instructions here: https://www.coin-or.org/PuLP/main/installing_pulp_at_home.html#testing-your-pulp-installation

Comment: But that doesn't seem to work anymore. If you locally save and then run `test_pulp.py` from here: https://github.com/coin-or/pulp/blob/5b80f9dc7f11376d317469d1a6ea31c83b2c9631/pulp/tests/test_pulp.py it should go through the tests, the first 10 or so lines of which will tell you which solvers are available. This will  tell you if being unable to access the solver is the problem.

Comment: Thanks @kabdulla , I run test_pulp.py and the only avaible is:
'Solver <class 'pulp.solvers.PULP_CBC_CMD'> available'
The same result is if I run 'pulp.pulpTestAll()'. I don't know why the other solvers are unavaiable but the problem is that if I run from python the program run but if I try to create an '.exe' file no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solver is available when you use pulp from your python sources, because that solver is the only one that comes with pulp. But when you run pyinstaller, it is no longer available (because you do not explicitly tell pyinstaller to copy it).

When packaging pulp with pyinstaller you need to tell pyinstaller to get the directory with the CBC solver that comes with pulp too. If not, you will only get the python code and then your packaged version will not find the CBC solver.

Assuming you have a `config.spec` file for pyinstaller, you have to edit it to something like the following (at least something like this works for me):

```
import sys
import os

block_cipher = None

def get_pulp_path():
    import pulp
    return pulp.__path__[0]

path_main = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[2]))

a = Analysis(['MAIN_SCRIPT.py'],
             pathex=[path_main],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)

a.datas += Tree(get_pulp_path(), prefix='pulp', excludes=["*.pyc"])

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz, a.scripts, exclude_binaries=True, name='NAME', debug=False, strip=False, upx=True, console=True)
coll = COLLECT(exe, a.binaries, a.zipfiles, a.datas, strip=False, upx=True, name='NAME')
```

And then run

```
pyinstaller -y config.spec
```

Answer (score 0):

1. This issue is because once you run pyinstaller, then it does not add
   the required dependencies for pulp as compared with dependencies of
   all other packages.
2. Explicit specification of the path for pulp folder is needed. The
   folder can be found in the directory where the python environment is
   installed.
3. Path for pulp folder can be found inside python path in

> Lib/site-packages/pulp

We need to pass path for pulp as an additional argument as follows:

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console --add-data "C:/Users/.../Lib/site-packages/pulp;pulp/"  "C:/Users/.../python_to_exe.py"
```

Where the first path is for pulp directory and second is for the python code having pulp dependency