# Pulp error occurs on executable when running PyInstaller with console option False

Tags: windows, pyinstaller, pulp

I was having a problem where pulp library was giving me an error:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'actualSolve'
```

I searched how to fix this and I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60926887/py-project-works-but-pyinstaller-gives-error-related-to-pulp) here on StackOverflow.

It worked with the following spec file

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None

def get_pulp_path():
    import pulp
    return pulp.__path__[0]

a = Analysis(['app.py'],
             pathex=['D:\\Documentos\\GitHub\\GraphFilter.py'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('.\\resources\\data', 'resources\\data'), ('.\\resources\\icons', 'resources\\icons')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             hooksconfig={},
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)

a.datas += Tree(get_pulp_path(), prefix='pulp', excludes=["*.pyc"])

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,  
          [],
          name='GraphFilter-2.0.1-win',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True,
          disable_windowed_traceback=False,
          target_arch=None,
          codesign_identity=None,
          entitlements_file=None , icon='resources\\icons\\hexagon.ico')
```

However, I want to generate the executable without the console option. Then, I changed the spec file to

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None

def get_pulp_path():
    import pulp
    return pulp.__path__[0]

a = Analysis(['app.py'],
             pathex=['D:\\Documentos\\GitHub\\GraphFilter.py'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('.\\resources\\data', 'resources\\data'), ('.\\resources\\icons', 'resources\\icons')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             hooksconfig={},
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)

a.datas += Tree(get_pulp_path(), prefix='pulp', excludes=["*.pyc"])

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,  
          [],
          name='GraphFilter-2.0.1-win',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
#         turned the console to false
          console=False, 
          disable_windowed_traceback=False,
          target_arch=None,
          codesign_identity=None,
          entitlements_file=None , icon='resources\\icons\\hexagon.ico')
```

and the problem from the beginning returns, giving me a

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'actualSolve'
```

You can check my source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/GraphFilter/GraphFilter) and the [Issue](https://github.com/GraphFilter/GraphFilter/issues/116) describing the problem.

Why can't I turn the console option off when dealing with pulp?

Opening the build files of the console equals True, I found a Tree-03.toc file with the following content:

```
[...]
 ('pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\win\\64\\cbc.exe',
   'D:\\Documentos\\GitHub\\GraphFilter.py\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\win\\64\\cbc.exe',
   'DATA'),
  ('pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\win\\64\\coin-license.txt',
   'D:\\Documentos\\GitHub\\GraphFilter.py\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\win\\64\\coin-license.txt',
   'DATA'),
  ('pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\win\\64\\__init__.py',
   'D:\\Documentos\\GitHub\\GraphFilter.py\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\win\\64\\__init__.py',
   'DATA'),
  ('pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\win\\32\\cbc.exe',
   'D:\\Documentos\\GitHub\\GraphFilter.py\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\win\\32\\cbc.exe',
   'DATA'),
  ('pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\win\\32\\coin-license.txt',
   'D:\\Documentos\\GitHub\\GraphFilter.py\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\win\\32\\coin-license.txt',
   'DATA'),
  ('pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\win\\32\\__init__.py',
   'D:\\Documentos\\GitHub\\GraphFilter.py\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\win\\32\\__init__.py',
   'DATA'),
  ('pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\osx\\64\\cbc',
   'D:\\Documentos\\GitHub\\GraphFilter.py\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\osx\\64\\cbc',
   'DATA'),
  ('pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\osx\\64\\coin-license.txt',
   'D:\\Documentos\\GitHub\\GraphFilter.py\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\osx\\64\\coin-license.txt',
   'DATA'),
  ('pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\osx\\64\\__init__.py',
   'D:\\Documentos\\GitHub\\GraphFilter.py\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\osx\\64\\__init__.py',
   'DATA'),
  ('pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\linux\\64\\cbc',
   'D:\\Documentos\\GitHub\\GraphFilter.py\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\linux\\64\\cbc',
   'DATA'),
  ('pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\linux\\64\\coin-license.txt',
   'D:\\Documentos\\GitHub\\GraphFilter.py\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\linux\\64\\coin-license.txt',
   'DATA'),
  ('pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\linux\\64\\__init__.py',
   'D:\\Documentos\\GitHub\\GraphFilter.py\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\linux\\64\\__init__.py',
   'DATA'),
  ('pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\linux\\32\\cbc',
   'D:\\Documentos\\GitHub\\GraphFilter.py\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\linux\\32\\cbc',
   'DATA'),
[...]
```

Inside the same file Tree-03.toc I found the same structure:

```
[...]
('pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\win\\64\\cbc.exe',
   'D:\\Documentos\\GitHub\\GraphFilter.py\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\win\\64\\cbc.exe',
   'DATA'),
  ('pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\win\\64\\coin-license.txt',
   'D:\\Documentos\\GitHub\\GraphFilter.py\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\win\\64\\coin-license.txt',
   'DATA'),
  ('pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\win\\64\\__init__.py',
   'D:\\Documentos\\GitHub\\GraphFilter.py\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\win\\64\\__init__.py',
   'DATA'),
  ('pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\win\\32\\cbc.exe',
   'D:\\Documentos\\GitHub\\GraphFilter.py\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\win\\32\\cbc.exe',
   'DATA'),
  ('pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\win\\32\\coin-license.txt',
   'D:\\Documentos\\GitHub\\GraphFilter.py\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\win\\32\\coin-license.txt',
   'DATA'),
  ('pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\win\\32\\__init__.py',
   'D:\\Documentos\\GitHub\\GraphFilter.py\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\win\\32\\__init__.py',
   'DATA'),
  ('pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\osx\\64\\cbc',
   'D:\\Documentos\\GitHub\\GraphFilter.py\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\osx\\64\\cbc',
   'DATA'),
  ('pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\osx\\64\\coin-license.txt',
   'D:\\Documentos\\GitHub\\GraphFilter.py\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\osx\\64\\coin-license.txt',
   'DATA'),
  ('pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\osx\\64\\__init__.py',
   'D:\\Documentos\\GitHub\\GraphFilter.py\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\osx\\64\\__init__.py',
   'DATA'),
  ('pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\linux\\64\\cbc',
   'D:\\Documentos\\GitHub\\GraphFilter.py\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\linux\\64\\cbc',
   'DATA'),
  ('pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\linux\\64\\coin-license.txt',
   'D:\\Documentos\\GitHub\\GraphFilter.py\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\linux\\64\\coin-license.txt',
   'DATA'),
  ('pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\linux\\64\\__init__.py',
   'D:\\Documentos\\GitHub\\GraphFilter.py\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\linux\\64\\__init__.py',
   'DATA'),
  ('pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\linux\\32\\cbc',
   'D:\\Documentos\\GitHub\\GraphFilter.py\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\linux\\32\\cbc',
   'DATA'),
  ('pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\linux\\32\\coin-license.txt',
   'D:\\Documentos\\GitHub\\GraphFilter.py\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\linux\\32\\coin-license.txt',
   'DATA'),
  ('pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\linux\\32\\__init__.py',
   'D:\\Documentos\\GitHub\\GraphFilter.py\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\pulp\\solverdir\\cbc\\linux\\32\\__init__.py',
   'DATA'),
[...]
```

But it won't work, the same error appears.

Generating without the onefile option, it works, and I am able to see the missing cbc file on the dist folder. I don't understand why I can generate it with onefile option without the console.

Comment: Is that the only difference between the spec files? it seems to be more a pyinstaller issue than a pulp issue. Check the build directory and look for the pulp library that is there and see if the cbc.exe file is present or not (you need to look in the subdirectories). I'm guessing in the first config it's there and in the second one it's not correctly copied.

Comment: I edited with what I found inside the build directory, related to pulp and this cbc.exe file. I believe that because I generate the executable with the onefile option, I am not able to see the file itself.

Comment: Interesting, so it's the combination of "onefile" + "no console"? Consider filing an issue in pyInstaller, maybe they can look into that. Your issue is that your packaged app is unable to find the cbc.exe file. This can be either because it's not present, because it doesn't find it or because it has no executable rights to it.

Comment: Followed your suggestion and opened [this issue](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/6359) on PyInstaller's GitHub.